# POST request with text

Tags: javascript, node.js, text, http-post, requesthandler

I'm with a weird problem, it seems correct to me, well.. I'll try to explain :

my function uploader:

```
var body = '<html>'+
'<head>'+
'<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" '+
'content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'+
'</head>'+
'<body>'+
'<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" '+
'method="post">'+
'<input type="text" name="text" multiple="multiple">'+
'<input type="submit" value="Submit" />'+
'</form>'+
'</body>'+
'</html>';

response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
response.write(body);
response.end();
```

and my upload handler :

```
function upload(response, request) {
console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
fields = {};
console.log("about to parse");
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});

response.write("You've sent the text: "+
    querystring.parse(request).text);


response.end(); 
}
```

I know it's an Ultra novice question but, what is going on ? Can any of you guess?

Result when uploaded any text is : undefined
Funny thing the Post is being catch, because before parse it is an object..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, the method is POST. Here are the issues:

- `querystring` is not defined for a POST request
- `multipart/form-data` is not necessary
- `multiple` is not a necessary attribute for `input type="text"`

Comment: Thanks Paul, it's been awhile, I'm a better programmer now, I swear. hehe happy new year : ]

Comment: @rcBytes Good to know. Happy new year.